# How can I make colorful background in WPF toolkit chart

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have this colourful graph that has been done in WinForms using a StripLine.  I'm trying to reimplement it in WPF, but I'm having trouble with the colored background.

How would I make the ChartArea's background behave like this in WPF Toolkit's Charting Controls?

[image: Colourful Graph]

Comment: Try using `LinearGradientBrush` as `Background` of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nitesh's hint and a bit of research into wpf styles, I've figured it out.

In the .xaml, I added a LinearGradientBrush, and a Style that uses it, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="YellowGreen" Offset="{Binding OnTargetColourChange}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="{Binding OnTargetColourChange}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="{Binding OnTargetMiddleColourChange}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="{Binding OverDryColourChange}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="{Binding OverDryColourChange}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0"/>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
  <Style x:Key="PlotAreaStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then when declaring the chart, I used the style:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart 
    Name="SimulatorChart"
    PlotAreaStyle="{StaticResource PlotAreaStyle}">
```

Finally I only had to update the values that were bound in my DataContext. (`OnTargetColourChange`, `OnTargetMiddleColourChange`, and `OverDryColourChange`)